# Не работает запрос DQL

Tags: sql, doctrine, dql

Не работает запрос dql

```
SELECT i, o, a 
  FROM TestBundle:OrderInvoice i 
    LEFT JOIN i.order o 
    LEFT JOIN o.address a 
    LEFT JOIN o.customer c 
  WHERE i.merchantId = :merchantId 
    AND o.status IN(9, 14, 15, 18) 
    AND (c.customerCode NOT LIKE :customerCode 
      OR c.lastname NOT LIKE :customerLastname 
      OR c.firstname NOT LIKE :customerFirstname) 
  ORDER BY i.invoiceId DESC
```

В частности не работает NOT LIKE. Если искать просто LIKE то все ок.

Суть проблемы в том, что нужно использовать NOT LIKE, но в случае его использования, выборка никак не меняется и выдается тоже самое как если бы я писал запрос без NOT LIKE

Подозреваю, что дело в JOIN, поскольку если я использую запрос на поля таблицы i, то это работает

Comment: ну если просто LIKE работает, то наверное надо юзать его)

Comment: В том-то и беда, что нужен функционал с NOT LIKE

Comment: @Svetoch так можно сделать составное условие через LIKE и перед ним уже добавить NOT.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не описали проблему, но могу предположить, что нужно так:

```
SELECT i, o, a 
  FROM TestBundle:OrderInvoice i 
    LEFT JOIN i.order o 
    LEFT JOIN o.address a 
    LEFT JOIN o.customer c 
  WHERE i.merchantId = :merchantId 
    AND o.status IN(9, 14, 15, 18) 
    AND (c.customerCode NOT LIKE :customerCode 
      AND c.lastname NOT LIKE :customerLastname 
      AND c.firstname NOT LIKE :customerFirstname) 
  ORDER BY i.invoiceId DESC
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что при NOT LIKE выдает тоже самое, что без этого условия. Даже если использовать такой запрос. 
SELECT i, o, a 
  FROM TestBundle:OrderInvoice i 
    LEFT JOIN i.order o 
    LEFT JOIN o.address a 
    LEFT JOIN o.customer c 
  WHERE i.merchantId = :merchantId 
    AND o.status IN(9, 14, 15, 18) 
    AND c.customerCode NOT LIKE :customerCode 
  ORDER BY i.invoiceId DESC